# SSL setup on WebSphere 6.1 for Windows

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, websphere, ssl-certificate

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to SSL security on WebSphere.

But basically I am calling a URL from my Java application hosted on WebSphere 6.1.  The URL is a web service which is secured via SSL.  As an example my URL is:

https://servername:portname/service

I call the web service using cURL using:

> --cert test.cer --key
>   test-privkey.pem  --pass "Password"

i.e. I have a .CER file and a .PEM file.

Please could someone advise how I configure WebSphere (through the Admin console) to secure "https://servername:portname/service" using the CER file and PEM file I have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever using a SSL URL, the JVM tries to recognize the certificate based on its trust store. The truststore file is named 'cacerts' and is present in the java/jre/lib/security folder.For the Webapp to recognize the SSL certificate, the root certificates* of the service must be imported into the cacerts store. This can be done with the help of 'keytool -import' in the java/jre/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tsec_sslexchangesigncerts.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using a SSL URL, the JVM tries to recognize the certificate based on its trust store. The truststore file is named 'cacerts' and is present in the java/jre/lib/security folder.For the Webapp to recognize the SSL certificate, the root certificates* of the service must be imported into the cacerts store. This can be done with the help of 'keytool -import' in the java/jre/bin folder.

- Root certificate is the Certifying Authority [CA] of a service i.e the Organization that provides the SSL certificate will have a CA cert to identify itself.

Let me know if you need more details.